# Logical error with return value from struct in c

Tags: c, struct

I have to return two values from a struct in C:

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Bar
{
        char *x;
        long y;
};

struct Bar funct();
struct Bar funct()
{
        struct Bar result;
        FILE *fp;
        long lSize;
        char *buffer;

        fp = fopen("list.txt", "rb");
        if (!fp) perror("list.txt"), exit(1);

        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        lSize = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);

        buffer = calloc(1, lSize+1);
        if(!buffer) fclose(fp), fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr), exit(1);

        if (1!=fread(buffer, lSize, 1, fp))
                fclose(fp), free(buffer), fputs("entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);

        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);

        printf("%ld\n", lSize);

        result.x = (char *) buffer;
        result.y = lSize;
}
```

Instead of structure, when I implement the same code in a char function, I used to get buffer as a char array, and lSize as 744.

My main function is the following:

```
int main()
{
        char *buffer;
        printf("Reading file...\n");
        //buffer = readFile();
        struct Bar result;
        buffer = result.x;
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        printf("%ld\n", result.y);
        //collect_character_distribution(buffer);


return 0;
}
```

But in structure, I don't get array value from *buffer, and I get 0 from lSize. I need to return both *buffer and lSize values. For this reason I have to use struct.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Umm... 'buffer'.... you freed it...

Comment: You are missing a `return` from `funct`.

Comment: Remove `free(buffer)`. You want to keep using this buffer.  Add `return result;` at the end.

Comment: I have done. The same output.

Comment: This function is correct, with those changes. If you still have a bug it must be in code that you didn't post. It's hard for us to debug code you didn't post. To get a good answer please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look at the edit M.M.

Comment: In the edited code you never call your function. You just declare an uninitialized variable `result` and then use it. Maybe you meant `struct Bar result = funct();`

Comment: I have declared struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are problems with your code -

```
 free(buffer);                      // don't free it earlier, you later use it 
 printf("%ld\n", lSize);
 result.x = (char *) buffer;       //casting is not needed
```

You `free` `buffer` and then make `result.x` to point to it . `free` it afterwards in calling function .

And this -

```
 if (1!=fread(buffer, lSize, 1, fp))
            fclose(fp), free(buffer), fputs("entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);
```

You should probably avoid writing like this . It represent quite unclearly .

You can clearly write like this -

```
 if(1!=fread(buffer, lSize, 1, fp)){
        fclose(fp);
        free(buffer);
        fputs("entire read fails", stderr);
        exit(1);
 }
```

make changes in pervious `if` also accordingly .

**Note** - You said you want to `return` something from function but your code doesn't seem to do so .

Comment: Just getting rid of the free call would fix the 'buffer' issue.  Since it's calloced, shoving it's address into the struct and returning the struct is fine.

Comment: ..but the comma operator thing is just horrible and your code above is a million times clearer:)

Comment: @MartinJames Yes , may be OP is new and didn't know about it . Thanks anyway  :-)

Comment: I wish devs would stop writing clever shit and then finding out they cannot debug it:)   Your code, I could step through line-by-line with the debugger. Easy!

Comment: Every expression gets evaluated in the second if statement. This means every function will be called not just exit.

Comment: @this I had a quick run , You are right , I had impression of `return` behaviour . Sorry for that . I will make corrections there .

Comment: Thank you ameyCU, but still I get the same results. Nothing is changed.

Comment: @Yusuf Did you return anything ?

Comment: @Yusuf Same means ?  Did you made change about `free(buffer)` , and what did you return from funtionc ?

Comment: Yes, I have done everything you wanted. I have returned the same thing I have returned before asking in stackoverflow.

Comment: "free it afterwards" - actually it should not be freed at all within this function, it is being returned

Comment: @Yusuf  As pointed out by @M.M  `free` buffer in function calling this function .

Comment: ameyCU, I have done everything, but still nothing happens.

Comment: When you call in main , you should do this -  `struct Bar result; result =funct();` in `main`.